# Error with testing on real device in xcode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, unrecognized-selector

I am making game in sprite kit XCode 7 and i am trying to testing it in real device but some error comes ,  it works fine in the simulator i don't what is the problem any help ?

here is the error

```
2015-09-08 15:04:46.986 Test Project[1239:60b] +[Test_Project.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100106d30
2015-09-08 15:04:46.988 Test Project[1239:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Test_Project.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100106d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18614e950 0x1926541fc 0x1861534f0 0x186151330 0x18607108c 0x1000fdefc 0x1000fd3d0 0x1000fd65c 0x189118670 0x1891183f4 0x18924fe68 0x1891aa6a0 0x18914d454 0x18929fe78 0x1891d2a10 0x18911cd30 0x18918f83c 0x18918c148 0x1891859ec 0x1891198cc 0x189118ad0 0x189185044 0x18bd33504 0x18bd33030 0x18610e890 0x18610e7f0 0x18610ca14 0x18604d6d0 0x1891841c8 0x18917efdc 0x1000fe6fc 0x192c47aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: add in `breakpoints navigator` breakpoints for `All Exceptions`  and add `Symbolic breakpont`  with symbol  `objc_exception_throw`.

It helps u understand where is problem and show line in code with error.

Comment: `nodeWithFileNamed` is available in iOS 8.0 and later. Make sure your device updated to iOS 8.

Comment: aha maybe this the problem cause i am trying to test it in ios 7.1 devices i will try on other device later thanks

Comment: @WangYudong can i ask you something , if i want to target ios 7 also what should i do ?

Comment: Can you post your code that calls `nodeWithFileNamed`?

Comment: @RUON, for testing on iOS 7 just go target deployment in project pane and lower the target deployment to iOS 7. it should do the trick.

Comment: Is it an SKNode or an SKSpriteNode? And is the file you are loading an image file or .sks scene? If you are loading an image file to an SKSpriteNode, use `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` instead. Otherwise, I have no idea how to target iOS 7 with `nodeWithFileNamed`.